# Purchase-ordering

Tags: c#, sql, mvc

This is the `Save` function on my `PurchaseOrder` model in my real world production system.

This code needs to write the state of the model to the database schema. It's grown over time as things have been added, so I'd like to work it a bit cleaner.

As you can see, it's gotten very messy and is hard to work with now. Do you think I would be best to split `Save` into two functions a `CreateNew` and `Update`?

```
internal void Save()
{
    int TotalJobs = 0;

    foreach (int c in Contracts)
    {
        Contract contract = Contract.LoadId(c);
        TotalJobs += contract.Quantity;
    }



    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStrings.ConnectionString))
    {
        if (PurchaseOrderId == null)
        {
            DynamicParameters p = new DynamicParameters(new
            {
                CompanyId,
                RecipientPersonId,
                CurrencyId,
                AddedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name,
                InitialOrderDate,
                ApprovedByPersonId,
                DeliveryDetail,
                EmailCC,
                DeliveryTypeId,
                DeliveryDateSingle,
                ScheduleDaysBeforePlan,
                WarrantyId,
                RepairId
            });
            p.Add("PurchaseOrderId", 0, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
            p.Add("CreateByPersonId", 0, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
            conn.Execute("material.PurchaseOrder_Add", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            PurchaseOrderId = p.Get<int>("PurchaseOrderId");
            CreateByPersonId = p.Get<int>("CreateByPersonId");
            foreach (PurchaseOrderLine l in Lines)
            {
                l.PurchaseOrderId = (int)PurchaseOrderId;
                l.Save(TotalJobs, Contracts, CompanyId);       // This adds the new line.
            }



            if (Contracts.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (int c in Contracts)
                {
                    if (c == 999999)
                        continue;

                    conn.Execute("material.PurchaseOrderContract_Update", new { PurchaseOrderId, ContractId = c }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                }

                if (!AllocateExcessToStock)
                {
                    conn.Execute("material.PurchaseOrder_UpdateBOM", new { PurchaseOrderId }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                }
                else
                {
                    conn.Execute("DELETE FROM prod.BillOfMaterialLine WHERE PurchaseOrderId = @PurchaseOrderId", new { PurchaseOrderId });
                }
            }

            if (WarrantyId > 0)
            {
                foreach(PurchaseOrderLine l in _lines)
                {
                    conn.Execute("INSERT INTO [prod].[WarrantyPart] ([WarrantyId], Description, Quantity, UnitPrice, PurchaseOrderLineId, AddedByPersonId) VALUES (@WarrantyId, @Description, @Quantity, @UnitPrice, @PurchaseOrderLineId, @AddedByPersonId)", new { WarrantyId, Description = l.Description, Quantity = l.Quantity, UnitPrice = l.UnitPrice, PurchaseORderLineId = l.PurchaseOrderDetailId, AddedByPersonId = CurrentUser.Get().PersonId  });                            
                }                                                  
            }

            if(RepairId > 0)
            {
                foreach (PurchaseOrderLine l in _lines)
                {
                    conn.Execute("INSERT INTO [prod].[RepairPart] ([RepairId], Description, Quantity, UnitPrice, PurchaseOrderLineId) VALUES (@RepairId, @Description, @Quantity, @UnitPrice, @PurchaseOrderLineId)", new { RepairId, Description = l.Description, Quantity = l.Quantity, UnitPrice = l.UnitPrice, PurchaseORderLineId = l.PurchaseOrderDetailId });
                }
            }

            foreach (var line in Lines)
            {
                if (line.DeliverySchedule != null && !line.OrigionalDetailId.HasValue)
                {
                    foreach (var plannedDelivery in line.DeliverySchedule)
                    {
                        plannedDelivery.PurchaseOrderDetailId = line.PurchaseOrderDetailId;
                        plannedDelivery.Add();
                    }
                }
            }
        }                                                               
        else
        {
            DynamicParameters p = new DynamicParameters(new
            {
                PurchaseOrderId,
                CompanyId,
                RecipientPersonId,
                CurrencyId,
                AmendedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name,
                InitialOrderDate,
                ApprovedByPersonId,
                DeliveryDetail,
                Revision,
                RevisionDetails,
                RepressSupplierEmail,
                EmailCC,
                DeliveryTypeId,
                DeliveryDateSingle,
                ScheduleDaysBeforePlan,
                WarrantyId,
                RepairId
            });
            conn.Execute("material.PurchaseOrder_Amend", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

            conn.Execute("DELETE FROM prod.BillOfMaterialLine WHERE PurchaseOrderId=@PurchaseOrderId and PurchaseOrderLineId is not null;", new { PurchaseOrderId });



            foreach (PurchaseOrderLine l in Lines)
            {
                int? currentDetailLineId = l.PurchaseOrderDetailId;
                l.PurchaseOrderId = (int)PurchaseOrderId;
                l.Save(TotalJobs, Contracts, CompanyId);
            }


            conn.Execute("DELETE FROM [material].[PurchaseOrderContract] WHERE PurchaseOrderId=@PurchaseOrderId", new { PurchaseOrderId });
            foreach (int c in Contracts)
            {
                conn.Execute("material.PurchaseOrderContract_Update",new {PurchaseOrderId, ContractId=c}, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            }


            foreach (var line in Lines)
            {
                if (line.DeliverySchedule != null && !line.OrigionalDetailId.HasValue)
                {
                    foreach (var plannedDelivery in line.DeliverySchedule)
                    {
                        plannedDelivery.PurchaseOrderDetailId = line.PurchaseOrderDetailId;
                        plannedDelivery.Add();
                    }
                }
            }

            Revision++; // update locally as the above procedure did in the DB (ensures email sent right)

        }
    }
}
```

**`PurchaseOrderLine.Save()`:**

```
public void Save(int TotalJobs, List<int> Contracts, int CompanyId)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStrings.ConnectionString))
    {
        DynamicParameters p = new DynamicParameters(new
        {
            PurchaseOrderId,
            Description,
            Quantity,
            UnitPrice,
            PurchaseOrderCodeId,
            PartId,
            LineType,
            PurchaseOrderRequestLineId
        });
        p.Add("PurchaseOrderDetailId", 0, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
        conn.Execute("material.PurchaseOrderLine_Add", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        PurchaseOrderDetailId = p.Get<int>("PurchaseOrderDetailId");

        if(OrigionalDetailId.HasValue)
        {
            // This is a revised line, take care of the old lines.
            int stock = 0;
            decimal PerJob = 0;

            if (TotalJobs > 0)
            {
                PerJob = AllocationPerJob;
                if (PerJob <= 0)
                    PerJob = Quantity / TotalJobs;

                stock = (int)(Quantity - (PerJob * TotalJobs));
            }
            int? ProductArea = PurchaseOrderCode.Loads().Where(x => x.PurchaseOrderCodeId == PurchaseOrderCodeId).FirstOrDefault().ProductAreaId;


            // Update planned deliverys.
            conn.Execute("UPDATE material.PurchaseOrderLineDelivery set PurchaseOrderDetailId = @PurchaseOrderDetailId where PurchaseOrderDetailId=@OrigionalDetailId", new { PurchaseOrderDetailId, OrigionalDetailId = OrigionalDetailId.Value });

            //Update recorded deliverys
            conn.Execute("UPDATE [material].[DeliveryLine]          set PurchaseOrderDetailId = @PurchaseOrderDetailId where PurchaseOrderDetailId=@OrigionalDetailId", new { PurchaseOrderDetailId, OrigionalDetailId = OrigionalDetailId.Value });

            // Delete the old line
            conn.Execute("delete from material.purchaseOrderLine where PurchaseOrderDetailId=@OrigionalDetailId", new { OrigionalDetailId });



            if (TotalJobs > 0)
            {
                foreach (int c in Contracts)
                {
                    Contract contract = Contract.LoadId(c);

                    if (ProductArea.HasValue)
                    {
                        conn.Execute("INSERT INTO prod.BillOfMaterialLine   (BillOfMaterialId,                              ProductAreaId,                          Description,                    FulfilById,                 PurchaseOrderId,    QuantityPerVehicle,         UnitPrice,                  Supplier,                       CompanyId,  PurchaseOrderLineId) " +
                                                                "VALUES     (@BillOfMaterialId,                             @ProductAreaId,                         @Description,                   @FulfilById,                @PurchaseOrderId,   @QuantityPerVehicle,        @UnitPrice,                 @Supplier,                      @CompanyId, @PurchaseOrderLineId)",
                                                                    new { BillOfMaterialId = contract.BillOfMaterialId, ProductAreaId = ProductArea.Value, Description = Description, FulfilById = 1, PurchaseOrderId, QuantityPerVehicle = PerJob, UnitPrice = UnitPrice, Supplier = CompanyName, CompanyId, PurchaseOrderLineId = PurchaseOrderDetailId });
                    }
                }
            }

            if (stock > 0)
            {
                if (ProductArea.HasValue)
                {
                    conn.Execute("INSERT INTO prod.BillOfMaterialLine   (BillOfMaterialId,                              ProductAreaId,                          Description,                    FulfilById,                 PurchaseOrderId,    QuantityPerVehicle,         UnitPrice,                  Supplier,                       CompanyId,  PurchaseOrderLineId) " +
                             "VALUES     (@BillOfMaterialId,                             @ProductAreaId,                         @Description,                   @FulfilById,                @PurchaseOrderId,   @QuantityPerVehicle,        @UnitPrice,                 @Supplier,                      @CompanyId, @PurchaseOrderLineId)",
                                 new { BillOfMaterialId = 1317, ProductAreaId = ProductArea.Value, Description = Description, FulfilById = 1, PurchaseOrderId, QuantityPerVehicle = stock, UnitPrice = UnitPrice, Supplier = CompanyName, CompanyId, PurchaseOrderLineId = PurchaseOrderDetailId });
                }

            }

        }
        else // This is a new line
        {
            if(TotalJobs > 0)   // Allocate to BoMs
            {
                decimal PerJob = AllocationPerJob;
                if (PerJob <= 0)
                    PerJob = Quantity / TotalJobs;

                int stock = (int)(Quantity - (PerJob * TotalJobs));
                int? ProductArea = PurchaseOrderCode.Loads().Where(x => x.PurchaseOrderCodeId == PurchaseOrderCodeId).FirstOrDefault().ProductAreaId;

                foreach (int c in Contracts)
                {
                    Contract contract = Contract.LoadId(c);
                    if (ProductArea.HasValue)
                    {
                        conn.Execute("INSERT INTO prod.BillOfMaterialLine    (BillOfMaterialId,                                 ProductAreaId,                              Description,                     FulfilById,  QuantityPerVehicle,           PurchaseOrderId,            UnitPrice,                  Supplier,               CompanyId,  PurchaseOrderLineId)" +
                                        " VALUES                             (@BillOfMaterialId,                                @ProductAreaId,                             @Description,                    1,           @QuantityPerVehicle,          @PurchaseOrderId,           @UnitPrice,                 @Supplier,              @CompanyId, @PurchaseOrderLineId)",
                                        new { BillOfMaterialId = contract.BillOfMaterialId, ProductAreaId = ProductArea.Value, Description = Description, QuantityPerVehicle = PerJob, PurchaseOrderId, UnitPrice, Supplier = CompanyName, CompanyId, PurchaseOrderLineId = PurchaseOrderDetailId });
                    }
                }

                if (stock > 0)
                {
                    // BOM ID = 1317
                    if (ProductArea.HasValue)
                    {
                        conn.Execute("INSERT INTO prod.BillOfMaterialLine    (BillOfMaterialId,                                 ProductAreaId,                              Description,                     FulfilById,  QuantityPerVehicle,           PurchaseOrderId,            UnitPrice,                  Supplier,               CompanyId,  PurchaseOrderLineId)" +
                                    " VALUES                             (@BillOfMaterialId,                                @ProductAreaId,                             @Description,                    1,           @QuantityPerVehicle,          @PurchaseOrderId,           @UnitPrice,                 @Supplier,              @CompanyId, @PurchaseOrderLineId)",
                                   new { BillOfMaterialId = 1317, ProductAreaId = ProductArea.Value, Description = Description, QuantityPerVehicle = stock, PurchaseOrderId, UnitPrice = UnitPrice, Supplier = CompanyName, CompanyId, PurchaseOrderLineId = PurchaseOrderDetailId });
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Database schema basically has to insert into a Bill of Materials table, a one-to-many contracts table, a one purchase order line to many planned delivery table, etc.

NOTE: This code is using the dapper.net framework.

Comment: Good first question, good job and welcome on Code Review!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Do you think I would be best to split Save into two functions a CreateNew and Update?

A very quick and loud : **YES !**

This method is just to long. By splitting it into `GetTotalJobs()`,  `Update(int, int)` and `Save(int)` you will make your code easier to read and maintain.

The former `Save()` method would then look like so

```
internal void Save()
{
    int totalJobs = GetTotalJobs();

    if (PurchaseOrderId == null)  
    {
        Save(totalJobs);
    }
    else
    {
        Update(PurchaseOrderId, totalJobs);
    }

}
```

with the `GetTotalJobs()` method looking like this

```
private int GetTotalJobs()
{
    int totalJobs = 0;

    foreach (int c in Contracts)
    {
        Contract contract = Contract.LoadId(c);
        totalJobs += contract.Quantity;
    }

    return totalJobs;
}
```

Based on the [NET naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) I changed the casing of the `TotalJobs` variable name to use `camelCase` casing.

But this little piece of code shows another strange thing. We are iterating over what seems a collection of `int` which is named `Contracts` and we use the values to call `Contract.LoadId()`. So changing the name of the property/field from `Contracts` to `ContractIds` and `LoadId()` to `LoadById()` will make things clearer for anyone who is reading/maintaining this code.

This will leave (just copied out of the former `Save()` method) the `Save(int)` method to

```
private void Save(int totalJobs)
{

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionStrings.ConnectionString))
    {
        DynamicParameters p = new DynamicParameters(new
        {
            CompanyId,
            RecipientPersonId,
            CurrencyId,
            AddedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name,
            InitialOrderDate,
            ApprovedByPersonId,
            DeliveryDetail,
            EmailCC,
            DeliveryTypeId,
            DeliveryDateSingle,
            ScheduleDaysBeforePlan,
            WarrantyId,
            RepairId
        });
        p.Add("PurchaseOrderId", 0, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
        p.Add("CreateByPersonId", 0, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
        conn.Execute("material.PurchaseOrder_Add", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
        PurchaseOrderId = p.Get<int>("PurchaseOrderId");
        CreateByPersonId = p.Get<int>("CreateByPersonId");
        foreach (PurchaseOrderLine l in Lines)
        {
            l.PurchaseOrderId = (int)PurchaseOrderId;
            l.Save(totalJobs, Contracts, CompanyId);       // This adds the new line.
        }



        if (Contracts.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (int c in Contracts)
            {
                if (c == 999999)
                    continue;

                conn.Execute("material.PurchaseOrderContract_Update", new { PurchaseOrderId, ContractId = c }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            }

            if (!AllocateExcessToStock)
            {
                conn.Execute("material.PurchaseOrder_UpdateBOM", new { PurchaseOrderId }, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
            }
            else
            {
                conn.Execute("DELETE FROM prod.BillOfMaterialLine WHERE PurchaseOrderId = @PurchaseOrderId", new { PurchaseOrderId });
            }
        }

        if (WarrantyId > 0)
        {
            foreach (PurchaseOrderLine l in _lines)
            {
                conn.Execute("INSERT INTO [prod].[WarrantyPart] ([WarrantyId], Description, Quantity, UnitPrice, PurchaseOrderLineId, AddedByPersonId) VALUES (@WarrantyId, @Description, @Quantity, @UnitPrice, @PurchaseOrderLineId, @AddedByPersonId)", new { WarrantyId, Description = l.Description, Quantity = l.Quantity, UnitPrice = l.UnitPrice, PurchaseORderLineId = l.PurchaseOrderDetailId, AddedByPersonId = CurrentUser.Get().PersonId });
            }
        }

        if (RepairId > 0)
        {
            foreach (PurchaseOrderLine l in _lines)
            {
                conn.Execute("INSERT INTO [prod].[RepairPart] ([RepairId], Description, Quantity, UnitPrice, PurchaseOrderLineId) VALUES (@RepairId, @Description, @Quantity, @UnitPrice, @PurchaseOrderLineId)", new { RepairId, Description = l.Description, Quantity = l.Quantity, UnitPrice = l.UnitPrice, PurchaseORderLineId = l.PurchaseOrderDetailId });
            }
        }

        foreach (var line in Lines)
        {
            if (line.DeliverySchedule != null && !line.OrigionalDetailId.HasValue)
            {
                foreach (var plannedDelivery in line.DeliverySchedule)
                {
                    plannedDelivery.PurchaseOrderDetailId = line.PurchaseOrderDetailId;
                    plannedDelivery.Add();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here I will only comment on the obvious and won't provide a rewrite because there isn't enough domain specific context avaible.

- add some vertical spacing to structure your code some more, hence increasing readability. For instance this

  > ```
  >  DynamicParameters p = new DynamicParameters(new
  >  {
  >      CompanyId,
  >      RecipientPersonId,
  >      CurrencyId,
  >      AddedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name,
  >      InitialOrderDate,
  >      ApprovedByPersonId,
  >      DeliveryDetail,
  >      EmailCC,
  >      DeliveryTypeId,
  >      DeliveryDateSingle,
  >      ScheduleDaysBeforePlan,
  >      WarrantyId,
  >      RepairId
  >  });
  >  p.Add("PurchaseOrderId", 0, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
  >  p.Add("CreateByPersonId", 0, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
  >  conn.Execute("material.PurchaseOrder_Add", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
  >  PurchaseOrderId = p.Get<int>("PurchaseOrderId");
  >  CreateByPersonId = p.Get<int>("CreateByPersonId");
  >  foreach (PurchaseOrderLine l in Lines)
  >  {
  >       l.PurchaseOrderId = (int)PurchaseOrderId;
  >       l.Save(totalJobs, Contracts, CompanyId);       // This adds the new line.
  >  }
  > ```

  would be much more readable like so

  ```
  DynamicParameters p = new DynamicParameters(new
  {
      CompanyId,
      RecipientPersonId,
      CurrencyId,
      AddedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name,
      InitialOrderDate,
      ApprovedByPersonId,
      DeliveryDetail,
      EmailCC,
      DeliveryTypeId,
      DeliveryDateSingle,
      ScheduleDaysBeforePlan,
      WarrantyId,
      RepairId
  });

  p.Add("PurchaseOrderId", 0, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);
  p.Add("CreateByPersonId", 0, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);

  conn.Execute("material.PurchaseOrder_Add", p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

  PurchaseOrderId = p.Get<int>("PurchaseOrderId");
  CreateByPersonId = p.Get<int>("CreateByPersonId");

  foreach (PurchaseOrderLine l in Lines)
  {
      l.PurchaseOrderId = (int)PurchaseOrderId;
      l.Save(totalJobs, Contracts, CompanyId);       // This adds the new line.
  }
  ```
- the magic number `999999`

  ```
  if (c == 999999)
      continue;
  ```

  should be extracted to a meaningful named constant. Adding braces `{}` to such single line `if` statements should als be done to make the code less error prone. In addition you are sometimes adding braces and sometimes don't. If you decide to use one style, you should stick to it.
- having a line that long like

  > ```
  >  conn.Execute("INSERT INTO [prod].[WarrantyPart] ([WarrantyId], Description, Quantity, UnitPrice, PurchaseOrderLineId, AddedByPersonId) VALUES (@WarrantyId, @Description, @Quantity, @UnitPrice, @PurchaseOrderLineId, @AddedByPersonId)", new { WarrantyId, Description = l.Description, Quantity = l.Quantity, UnitPrice = l.UnitPrice, PurchaseORderLineId = l.PurchaseOrderDetailId, AddedByPersonId = CurrentUser.Get().PersonId  });
  > ```

  makes it quite hard to grasp at all. One will need to scroll a long way to the right. You should find a way to make this more readable, maybe something like so

  ```
  conn.Execute("INSERT INTO [prod].[WarrantyPart] " +
      "([WarrantyId], Description, Quantity, UnitPrice, PurchaseOrderLineId, AddedByPersonId) " +
      "VALUES (@WarrantyId, @Description, @Quantity, @UnitPrice, @PurchaseOrderLineId, @AddedByPersonId)", 
      new { WarrantyId, Description = l.Description,
          Quantity = l.Quantity, UnitPrice = l.UnitPrice,
          PurchaseORderLineId = l.PurchaseOrderDetailId,
          AddedByPersonId = CurrentUser.Get().PersonId });
  ```

  Assuming these strings will be used somewhere else too, you should extract them to some meaningful named constants, to have only one place where you need to make changes if needed.
- the usage of such an extension method like `Execute()` of the `SqlConnection` is IMO to much abstraction. Anyone who isn't familiar with this method will very often need to visit this method to grasp what is done there.